# Was annotating and deleting a answer at the same time intended?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderator

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33686/20636) was annotated as needing sources and deleted by a single vote at the same time.

I agree adding sources would improve it, but it seems a bit heavy handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an oversight on my part. I realized that I had neglected to add the post notice earlier when I went back to remove all posts without sources.

Comment: It's undeleted now, after reviewing your edits.